# Open another question with the same title when the context is different?

Tags: support

Like in ["Target" vs. "destination"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4157/target-vs-destination), I also have the question whether to choose *target* or *destination*, but in a different context. I am talking about a list on which someone enters the place in a warehouse where stuff is to be placed (*destination bin* vs. *target bin*). I think neither of the contexts given in above question match my case.

So shall I add a comment to that question or shall I start a new one with the same title?

Comment: I would go with a new question with the same title. Perhaps you can get an answer before it is closed.

Comment: @Torpour: Why would the question get closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could ask a new question with a slightly different title, i.e. including your context. So, instead of *Target vs Destination*, title it *Target bin vs Destination bin*, or something similar.

In your description, make sure you mention the other question and why it fails to answer your question. Also, look up both words in a good dictionary or two, and tell us exactly why the definitions aren't helping you to choose the right word.